# Link to a file and javascript simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

Is it possible to link to a file as noticias.php and call a javascript simultaneously?

```
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('novidades');" class="linktriangulo"></a>
```

my function in noticias.php file:

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
    $("#novidades").hide();
    $("#noticias").hide();
    $("#eventos").hide();
    $("#"+divId).toggle();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more?  That's very unclear.

Comment: What's the desired effect? Once you click on a link, the current page is going to "end", so executing Javascript on it won't make much sense. The only thing that *would* make sense is to execute Javascript, and have the Javascript redirect when it's done. That's pretty horrible for usability though, plain links are much preferred.

Comment: There's nowhere near enough information here. Are you wanting to run some JavaScript **then** go to the PHP file? Or do you want to run the JavaScript **and** open the PHP file in a new browser tab/window?

Comment: Something like
<a href="noticias.php javascript:toggleDiv('novidades');" class="linktriangulo"></a>

Comment: What's the point of toggling a div when you're leaving the page anyway...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to call javascript inside  tag , u can use this approach :

```
<a onclick="jsfunction()" href="#">
```

Or

```
<a onclick="jsfunction()" href="javascript:void(0);">
```

Comment: noticias.php is a new page and javascript is for toggle a div on or off

Comment: I want to link and execute the js function simultaneously

This won't work
<a onclick="jsfunction()" href="noticias.php">